# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void completeMilestoneDate(List<Case>, List<Case>) from the type CompleteMilesone

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I am not getting whats going wrong here ?

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before update) {
    CompleteMilesone.completeMilestoneDate(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
}
```

and CompleteMilesone

```
public class CompleteMilesone {

    public static void completeMilestoneDate(List<Case> newCases, List<Case> oldCases){
        List<Id> caseIds1 = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> caseIds2 = new List<Id>();

        for(Case cs : newCases){
            if(oldCases.get(cs.Id).Status == 'AAA' && newCases.get(cs.Id).Status == 'BBB'){
                caseIds1.add(cs.Id);
            } 
            else if(oldCases.get(cs.Id).Status == 'BBB' && newCases.get(cs.Id).Status == 'CCC'){
                caseIds2.add(cs.Id);
            }
        }

        if(!caseIds1.isEmpty())
            MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds1, 'KKK1', System.now());
        else if(!caseIds2.isEmpty())
             MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds2, 'KKK2', System.now());
    }
}
```

I am getting the below errors:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void completeMilestoneDate(List<Case>, List<Case>) from the type CompleteMilesone
```

[image]

I am simply formatting the below code. So that no logic is inside Case Trigger since I have almost 50 triggers in case object

[image]

One more screen shots:

[image]

Comment: Note you have a typo in your class name.

Comment: Also, you cannot do `oldCases.get(cs.Id)` on a List. You need a `Map<Id, Case>` for that

Comment: Please use ***text*** to share your error messages and code. It is much more broadly accessible, and it can also be *searched*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Trigger.new` is `List<SObject>`. `List<SObject>` can't be passed to `List<Case>` parameter, because it could be not only `Case`, but other `SObject` (SObject instanceof Case == false). So change types of parameter and then cast it to `List<Case>`

```
public static void completeMilestoneDate(List<SObject> newSobjs, List<SObject> oldSobjs){
    List<Case> newCases = (List<Case>) newSobjs;
    List<Case> oldCases = (List<Case>) oldSobjs;
    ...
}
```

Then according do your screenshot you didn't save `CompleteMilesone` class because of trying to call `oldCases.get(cs.Id)`. Container `List` doesn't have `get` method, that accepts `Id` as parameter. if you want to get old Case record based on Case Id:

```
Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap =  new Map<Id, Case>(oldSobjs);
```

But in this case, it is better to pass `Trigger.oldMap` as second parameter of `completeMilestoneDate` method.

**So your final version of code looks like:**

```
public class CompleteMilesone {

    public static void completeMilestoneDate(List<SObject> newSobjs, Map<Id,SObject> oldSobjsMap){
        List<Case> newCases = (List<Case>) newSobjs;
        Map<Id, Case> oldCasesMap = (Map<Id, Case>)oldSobjsMap;
        List<Id> caseIds1 = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> caseIds2 = new List<Id>();

        for(Case cs : newCases){
            Case oldCs = oldCasesMap.get(cs.Id);
            if(oldCs.Status == 'AAA' && cs.Status == 'BBB'){
                caseIds1.add(cs.Id);
            } else if(oldCs.Status == 'BBB' && cs.Status == 'CCC'){
                caseIds2.add(cs.Id);
            }
        }
        if(!caseIds1.isEmpty())
            MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds1, 'KKK1', DateTime.now());
        else if(!caseIds2.isEmpty())
             MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds2, 'KKK2', DateTime.now());
    }
}
```

**Final version of trigger:**

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before update) {
    CompleteMilesone.completeMilestoneDate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
}
```

Comment: According to your screenshot you weren't able to successfully save `CompleteMilesone` class. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JavaBest that is what I am talking about. I've updated my post. It now describes your problem

Comment: ohk. I have added screen shot which is the error now I am facing

Comment: Thanks, Now why this is not saving ?`trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before update) {
    CompleteMilesone.completeMilestoneDate(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
}`

Comment: @JavaBest and I've updated my post one more time with trigger :)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at entirely the wrong compile error. This one is your blocker:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Id) from the type List

Right now, your `CaseMilesone` (sic) class does not compile. If you load the Apex Class through the Setup menu, you'll probably see it is empty. Your method will not exist until you get this class to compile (and preferably rename the class).

The reason this code fails to compile is that you have changed the `Type` you are using, but not how you use it. In your trigger, you have:

```
if (trigger.oldMap.get(someId).SomeField__c == 'Some Value' && ...)
```

But in your service layer, you have:

```
if (oldCases.get(someId).SomeField__c == 'Some Value && ...)
```

You have the same problem with your new collection as well. You are using **`Map<Id, Case>`** in your trigger, but instead used **`List<Case>`** in your service. You are not using the same `Type` in both examples. The `List` type does not have a `get(Id)` method signature, so your method cannot compile.

You need to change *both* parameters to `Map<Id, Case>`:

```
public class CaseService
{
    public static void doWork(Map<Id, Case> newMap, Map<Id, Case> oldMap)
    {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Then in your trigger, you would call:

```
CaseService.doWork(trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap)
```

Obviously, rename the `doWork` method to use a more descriptive name.